# Laravel 5 Bleeding From Protected $Hidden

Tags: laravel-5

In my `App/User` I have the following:

```
protected $hidden = ['name', 'password', 'email', 'remember_token','created_at', 'updated_at','api_token','gmail_id','Personal'];
```

My understanding was that this was used to prevent sensitive information stored in the database as part of the model from leaking out into the view.

But it doesn't seem to be working?

When I query the `users` table from a many-to-many relationship, and `print_r()` my variable, I get to see all the data from the given row in the Users table, including the hidden columns.

What am I doing wrong?

In the controller : `$achievements = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->achievements()->orderBy('Time', 'desc')->take(1)->get();`

In the view: `{{print_r($achievements)}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel `$hidden` in a model just refers to its JSON representation - the JSON that Laravel will generate when you ask to serialize a model to JSON.

In your case you're just asking PHP to dump the raw values loaded from the database - which do include your hidden fields. But that dumping is outside of Laravel's knowledge and is straight PHP, where as `$hidden` is only a Laravel construct

Comment: Isn't the `$achievements` variable however within Laravel's scope? I'm just asking php to print the value of `$achievements`, which was generated using a laravel `get()` so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper - sort of; if Laravel obeyed $hidden as you think it does, that would imply that it never retrieved those values from the DB into the model and they really were hidden / invisible. But really, think of it like a flag that tells Laravel: "ok to pull me [the attribute] from the DB, but just dont display me when my model is being transformed into JSON."

Comment: @SummerDeveloper if you truly dont want to pull those columns back from the DB at all (and thereby even making them invisible in the raw PHP print_r call) you'll just need to tell Laravel/Eloquent not pull them at all and be explicit about your SQL select columns `User->select("first_name", "last_name", "id")...` etc

Comment: I thought get() was transforming them into JSON though, what method can I use to be able to dump the `User` table while respecting the `hidden` fields and not having to change all my queries?

Comment: @SummerDeveloper no `get()` is just what materializes your SQL array and fetches those records back from the DB. It has nothing to do with representation of the model (JSON). Since `$hidden` is respected by both array and JSON serialization if you first ask Laravel to convert your raw array to a Laravel-massaged array via `toArray()` it should do the sanitization for you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization